# Changing button "status" using Angular?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have a table. Each element in this table is an order, and there is a button to change the status of this order. I would like this button's text to change to the next status in line, so ie. if the order is on "packed" the button should read "In delivery".

The button is working, and just changes to next in an array in PHP and parse that to mySQL. But I can't figure out how to show the text on the button (Im very new at angular):

Can I make a local array in angular in forms of variables and somehow filter accordingly to my JSON objects in if statements? (The status's are purely strings) How would I get that to display properly on the button?

Table code:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in orders | filter: {area: areaFilter} | filter: {status: statusFilter}">
                <td>{{ x.orderID }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.customerID }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.area }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.orderType }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.trashcanType }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.status }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.renonord }}</td>


                <td class="text-right">
                  <button href="#" ng-controller="updateStatus" data-id="{{ x.orderID }}" ng-click="doClick()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Set to next status
</button>
                </td>
```

Relevant controllers I use:

```
  app.controller('getOrders3', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.sortType     = 'orderID';
      $scope.sortReverse  = true;
      $scope.search   = '';

      $http.get("...filterOrders.php")
      .then(function (response) {$scope.orders = response.data.orders;});
      $scope.$on('updatedModel', function(event, []) {
       //alert("this long");
       $http.get("...filterOrders.php")
      .then(function (response) {$scope.orders = response.data.orders;})
      event.stopPropagation();
      });
    });





    app.controller('updateStatus', function($attrs, $scope, $http) {
       //$scope.updateStatus {};
       $scope.doClick = function () {
          var id = ($attrs).id;
          $http.get("...changeStatusTest.php",{params:{"orderID" : id}});
          //alert(id);
          $scope.$emit('updatedModel', []);

    }});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and controller code?

Comment: Ive added the relevant codesnippets :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` to achieve this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Order 1</td>
    <td ng-if="filter=='condition1'"><button>In delivery</button></td>
    <td ng-if="filter=='condition2'"><button>Dispatched</button></td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work, but I need to set the condition to the next condition in line, ie. an array. Any idea how to approach that?

Comment: If you go with this, use ng-if, not ng-show so all of the buttons aren't in your HTML for each row in your table. Using ng-show will add unnecessary overhead and memory consumption here, as well as multiple elements with the same id, which could be problematic later.

Answer (score 0):

As you provide no data I have assume this can help you

```
<button class="your class" ng-class="data.isPacked == 1 ? 'active': ''" ng-click="$root.packedDelivery(data);">{{(data.isPacked == 0) ? 'Packed': 'Delivery'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added data now.. I dont understand this snippet however, and Im trying to learn. What root does click look at ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add something like the following to your controller:

```
$scope.statuses = [foo,fubar,snafu].split(",")
$scope.nextStatus = function(current) {
    var curIndex = $scope.statuses.indexof(current)
    if ( curIndex >=0 && curIndex < $scope.statuses - 1) { 
         return $scope.statuses[curIndex+1]
    } else (curIndex < 0) {
        return  $scope.statuses[0]
    }
    return $scope.statuses[$scope.statuses.length-1]
}
```

}

Then render the button something like this:

```
<button href="#" ng-controller="updateStatus" data-id="{{ x.orderID }}" ng-click="doClick()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">{{nextStatus(x.status}}
</button>
```

Comment: I made the controller like this now, but it crashes everything else; https://codeshare.io/4PMkj

Comment: The code I suggested should just come at the beginning of your controller. not in the middle of another function. I didn't notice that you had an updatestatus controller as a separate controller previously. This is overkill, you can add these things to the same controller that you're getting the data from.

Comment: I tried that too, but no matter where I put it it will give me an syntax error at this line; elseif (curIndex < 0) {
           return  $scope.statuses[0]
 }

Comment: Can angular controllers not handle 2 scopes ?

Comment: Oh my bad. I just wrote the code here, not in an editor. It's simply else, not elseif.

Comment: I got rid of the syntax error, but console is throwing me an error at the button.. .but it should be formatted correctly? https://codeshare.io/4PMkj

Comment: There's a missing paren in the html. This {{nextStatus(x.status}} should be changed to this: {{nextStatus(x.status)}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112703/discussion-between-nicklasn-and-mike-feltman).